# Simplify SpringBootTest startup with JpaRepositories

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Curious if this is a possible approach to shortening run time of `@SpringBootTest` integration tests.

I have an integration tests which interacts with 1 repository, I was thinking I could do something like:

```kotlin
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = [MyRepository::class])
@SpringBootTest(classes = [MyComponent::class, MyService::class])
class MyComponentIntegrationtest {
  // tests
}
```

But I'm getting an error

> Parameter 1 of constructor in com.my.services.MyService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following, but curious if there's a better way?

```kotlin
@Import(MyComponent::class, MyService::class)
@DataJpaTest
class MyComponentIntegrationtest {
  // tests
}
```